# Divide each plane of cube by its median without loop

Tags: python, numpy

I need to normalize a numpy data cube say:

```
cube = np.random.random(100000).reshape(10,100,100)
```

and then normalise each of the 10 resulting planes by the median. So, e.g. for the first plane

```
cube[0, :, :] /= np.median(cube[0, :, :])
```

I just want to avoid a loop if possible  
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a list of axes to `np.median` and then expand via `None` (`np.newaxis`):

```
>>> cube = np.random.random(100000).reshape(10,100,100)
>>> simple = cube / np.median(cube,axis=[1,2])[:,None,None]
>>> 
>>> brute = cube.copy()
>>> for i in range(10):
...     brute[i, :, :] /= np.median(cube[i, :, :])
...     
>>> np.allclose(brute, simple)
True
```

but to be honest, looping over the shortest axis often isn't so bad performance-wise if the other axes are much longer.

Comment: Perfect, would have never thought about that  thanks!

Comment: If you are using version 1.9.0 or newer of numpy, then instead of `np.median(cube,axis=[1,2])[:,None,None]`, you can use `np.median(cube, axis=[1, 2], keepdims=True)`.